# OTEL jaeger exporter doesn't export data with strange error

Tags: jaeger, otel

Instrumentation OTEL for golang while trying to send traces to jaeger returns error

```
{"level":"error","ts":1700656827.118944,"logger":"otel","caller":"metric/metrics.go:112","msg":"Error","service.name":"service","error":"traces export: Post \"http://localhost:4318/v1/traces\": EOF","stacktrace":"kit/server/metric.zapErrorHandler.Handle\n\t/Users/j.doe/GolandProjects/service/server/metric/metrics.go:112\ngo.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/global.(*ErrDelegator).Handle\n\t/Users/j.doe/GolandProjects/service/vendor/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/global/handler.go:48\ngo.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/global.Handle\n\t/Users/j.doe/GolandProjects/service/vendor/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/global/handler.go:101\ngo.opentelemetry.io/otel.Handle\n\t/Users/j.doe/GolandProjects/service/vendor/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/handler.go:48\ngo.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace.(*batchSpanProcessor).processQueue\n\t/Users/j.doe/GolandProjects/service/vendor/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace/batch_span_processor.go:317\ngo.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace.NewBatchSpanProcessor.func1\n\t/Users/j.doe/GolandProjects/service/vendor/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace/batch_span_processor.go:128"}
```

What's wrong?
Jaeger v1.6 works in docker container at localhost:4318

Comment: 1) What's in the Jaeger logs? (What if you raise its debug level to maximum, if possible?); 2) Run Wireshark or a similar tool to capture that traffic and try to make sense of what the client tries to send; may be Jaeger answers something before closing its side of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

The truth was so far...
On jaeger wasn't activated otlp handler on 4318 port
to do this, set `COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true` for jaeger, and full example:

```
docker run -d --name jaeger \
   -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HOST_PORT=:9411 \
   -e COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true \
   -p 6831:6831/udp \
   -p 6832:6832/udp \
   -p 5778:5778 \
   -p 16686:16686 \
   -p 4317:4317 \
   -p 4318:4318 \
   -p 14250:14250 \
   -p 14268:14268 \
   -p 14269:14269 \
   -p 9411:9411 \
   jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```